# Read user's email on android gtalk

Tags: android, email, gmail, android-intent

i am trying to make an application for android that actually needs to reads users email with users permission. Is it possible to read the email from user's inbox from gtalk or the inbuilt email app and get the text in the body and subject with intents or anything?Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Querying the Google Email App is not supported and is locked down. 3rd party apps can't access it.